# substring() generates error in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I am getting a error when using this substring(). I am trying to get initials of first, middle, and last and then convert to upper case.

```
public String initials() {
    String initials = first.substring(0, 1) + middle.substring(0, 1) 
            + last.substring(0, 1);
    return initials.toUpperCase();
}
```

That is the code and this is the output it is giving me..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
null, null null at name.Name.initials(Name.java:75)
   at name.NameDriver.main(NameDriver.java:30)
   Java Result: 1
```

Line 75 is

```
String initials = first.substring(0, 1) + middle.substring(0, 1)
```

Line 30 in NameDriver is

```
System.out.print(name1.initials());
```

Comment: Where is `first`, `middle` and `last` declared and initialized?

Comment: They are declared as private String. They are set to null. then are suppose to change when the user inputs the name.

Comment: Most likely one or more of `first, middle, last` String variables are null.

Comment: Inside `initials()` first you should check if all the variables are not null before calling substring on them.

Comment: If `first` `middle` and `last` are members of the Name class, are you giving them values during or after you construct your Name object?  Can you post your NameDriver code?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the usage of substring(), but rather with the fact that you should not invoke a method (which in this case happens to be substring()) on null.

Comment: I can't post my full code here as it is for a homework assignment and I don't want it to be public. Is there anyway I can delete this after I receive help?

Comment: Your question needs better explanation ..

Answer (score 5):

This error is unrelated to the `substring` method and appears to be because `first`, `middle`, and `last` are null and this method can only be performed on a String.

The easiest way to stop this error occuring would be to add something like this at the start of your `initials` method:

`if(first == null || middle == null || last == null) return "Not all names have been entered";`

However, you may also want to consider that not everyone has a middle name.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Andy just replied, just guard against any of these 3 being null.
Maybe just create and auxiliary function like:

```
private static String firstLetter(String name) {
  if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
    return "";
  }
  return name.substring(0, 1);
}
```

Then you can just change your code to:

```
public String initials() {
    String initials = firstLetter(first) + firstLetter(middle) + firstLetter(last);
    return initials.toUpperCase();
}
```